# Invalid set index 'velocity' (on base: 'StaticBody2D') with value of type 'Vector2' error in Godot

Tags: error-handling, godot, godot4

In my main script (main.gd), I wrote:

```
var asteroidPath = preload("res://Asteroid.tscn")
func _process(delta):
    if time:
        time -= 1
    if time <= 0:
        var Asteroid = asteroidPath.instantiate()
        $Asteroids.add_child(Asteroid)
        Asteroid.velocity = Vector2(sin(rng.randf_range(-PI,PI)) * rng.randf_range(-4, 4), cos(rng.randf_range(-PI,PI)) * rng.randf_range(-4, 4))
        var size = rng.randf_range(2, 0.8)
        Asteroid.scale = Vector2(size, size)
        Asteroid.health = 1
        time = 150
```

and Godot throws the error shown in the title. In my asteroids script, which is indeed attached to the StaticBody2D, I clearly defined velocity as a Vector2. These are the first four lines of my code in the Asteroids script:

```
extends StaticBody2D
var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.new()
var rotation_velocity = 0
var velocity = Vector2.ZERO
```

It has been working perfectly fine previously, until recently, when it mysteriously broke. I did not change or edit those blocks of code. This code only entails the most crucial parts of the problem.
I tried writing `print(Asteroid.velocity)`, but it just returned a similar error:
`Invalid get index 'velocity' (on base: 'StaticBody2D')`

I also tried looking this problem up on the Godot documentation and Q&A, and made sure that Asteroid defined velocity, but none of the questions matched my situation.
I have tried removing the line completely, but it merely returns the same error on a different line: `Asteroid.health = 1`

Comment: What you describe sounds like the script is not attached or not loading. You say you changed nothing and it stopped working... Are you using a pre-release of Godot 4.1? It could be this bug: https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/76941 - you would fix your project by detaching the script and attaching it again. There should be a fix for the stable release of Godot 4.1. Right now moving files and folders in the pre-release versions is bugged.